# Difference Equation Blowing Up - C

Tags: c

for one my classes I am supposed to write a program that implements a differential equation to find the temperature of a 100 degree rod where both ends are dipped in an ice bath. The difference equation is given to solve it. I have an array that is split in the x direction as the segments of the rod and in the y direction as the iterations of time. An r value determines the speed at which the rod cools. It might be worth noting that how the actual program is implemented isn't that important, this program is meant to run on a computer cluster and the point of the assignment is to introduce us to the issuing of jobs on the cluster. The program still has to be correct though (obviously), and I can't even get to that point.

I'm having trouble with my program, because my array seems to start getting garbage data at (seemingly) random points in the time iterations. I have Netbeans and have tried debugging this but the last time I did it I could not peek into the different elements of the array variable (making the debugging process practically useless) and now I can even get it to stop at my break point. I've been banging my head against this problem for a while and am hoping someone much wiser than me can simply "see" the problem and help me out.

Thanks.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int segmentsl;
    int segmentst;
    float rvalue;
    int i,j;
    float k;

    //Pull in initial data
    printf("Enter as integers without spaces: Number of Segments - Length, Number of Segments - time ,value\n");
    scanf("%d,%d,%f", &segmentsl,&segmentst,&rvalue);

    float tempvstime[segmentsl][segmentst];


    //at t0 -> temp = 100sin(pi*x)
    for(i = 0; i < segmentsl; i++){
          k = (float)(i/(segmentsl-1));
          tempvstime[i][0] = 100*sin(M_PI*k); 
          printf("%f,",tempvstime[i][0]); 
    }

    printf("\n\n\nEND OF INITIALIZATION \n\n\n"); 

    for(j = 0; j < (segmentst-1); j++){
      for(i = 0; i < segmentsl; i++){
        if(i == 0 || i == (segmentsl - 1)){tempvstime[i][j] = 0;}
        else{
        tempvstime[i][j+1] = (rvalue*tempvstime[i-1][j]) + ((1-(2*rvalue))*tempvstime[i][j]) + (rvalue*tempvstime[i+1][j]); 
        }
      }
    }


    for(j = 0; j < segmentst; j++){
            for(i = 0; i < segmentsl; i++){
            printf("%f,",tempvstime[i][j]);
                if(i == segmentsl - 1){printf("\n");}
            }
    }

}
```

Here's some sample output:

```
Enter as integers without spaces: Number of Segments - Length, Number of Segments - time ,value
6,10,0.5
0.000000,58.778526,95.105652,95.105652,58.778522,0.000000,


END OF INITIALIZATION 


0.000000,58.778526,95.105652,95.105652,58.778522,0.000000,
0.000000,47.552826,76.942093,76.942085,47.552826,0.000000,
0.000000,38.471046,62.247456,62.247459,38.471043,0.000000,
0.000000,31.123728,50.359253,50.359249,31.123730,0.000000,
0.000000,25.179626,40.741489,40.741493,25.179625,0.000000,
0.000000,20.370745,32.960560,32.960556,-nan,0.000000,
0.000000,16.480280,26.665649,-nan,-nan,0.000000,
0.000000,13.332825,-nan,-nan,-nan,0.000000,
0.000000,-nan,-nan,-nan,-nan,0.000000,
0.000000,-nan,-nan,-nan,-nan,0.000000,
```

Comment: It's not Netbeans to be fair, but I hate it. Don't use it for C, there's no reason. Debugging with it, IME, is like trying to figure out a magic trick. It seems to always show stale data, or sometimes, but there's no rhyme or reason that I could tell.

Comment: "nan" is not garbage.  It stands for "not a number."  You calculation is somehow creating a floating point value that cannot be represented.  See this link  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN  Have you tried using double types instead of float? I would also recommend breaking apart the statement, "       tempvstime[i][j+1] = (rvalue*tempvstime[i-1][j]) + ((1-(2*rvalue))*tempvstime[i][j]) + (rvalue*tempvstime[i+1][j]); 
" and assign each sub-calculation to a separate variable and view the values for debugging purposes.

Comment: I don't really understand how it could be doing that... From my limited experience nan is usually a divide by zero error. But I'm not dividing anywhere (outside the first initialization of the array which only occurs once). I'll try your other suggestions

Comment: From [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Infinity-and-NaN.html): NaN is unordered: it is not equal to, greater than, or less than anything, including itself. x == x is false if the value of x is NaN. You can use this to test whether a value is NaN or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the integer division in

```
k = (float)(i/(segmentsl-1));
```

You set the wrong end-points:

```
for(j = 0; j < (segmentst-1); j++){
  for(i = 0; i < segmentsl; i++){
    if(i == 0 || i == (segmentsl - 1)){tempvstime[i][j] = 0;}
    else{
    tempvstime[i][j+1] = (rvalue*tempvstime[i-1][j]) + ((1-(2*rvalue))*tempvstime[i][j]) + (rvalue*tempvstime[i+1][j]); 
    }
  }
}
```

If `i` is 0 or the last index, you set `tempvstime[i][j]`, for the other `i`, you set `tempvstime[i][j+1]`.

You should set `tempvstime[i][j+1]` also for the end-points. Otherwise, in the next iteration, you use uninitialised (garbage) values, invoking undefined behaviour.

With that change, and floating point division when setting `k`, I get reasonable values:

```
6,10,0.5
0.000000,58.778526,95.105652,95.105652,58.778522,0.000000,


END OF INITIALIZATION 


0.000000,58.778526,95.105652,95.105652,58.778522,0.000000,
0.000000,47.552826,76.942093,76.942085,47.552826,0.000000,
0.000000,38.471046,62.247456,62.247459,38.471043,0.000000,
0.000000,31.123728,50.359253,50.359249,31.123730,0.000000,
0.000000,25.179626,40.741489,40.741493,25.179625,0.000000,
0.000000,20.370745,32.960560,32.960556,20.370747,0.000000,
0.000000,16.480280,26.665649,26.665653,16.480278,0.000000,
0.000000,13.332825,21.572968,21.572964,13.332827,0.000000,
0.000000,10.786484,17.452894,17.452896,10.786482,0.000000,
0.000000,8.726447,14.119690,14.119688,8.726448,0.000000,
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice that this line:

```
k = (float)(i/(segmentsl-1));
```

is performing integer division. Since `i<segmentsl` it will be the case that `i/segmentsl` is 0. This is probably not what you intend.

It is also the case that farther in your program, you use `tempvstime[i][j+1]` and `tempvstime[i][j]`, while both should be `j+1`.

A modified version of your program which runs correctly and has altered variable names and fewer parentheses in the math follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void){
    int width, maxt;
    float rvalue;
    int i,t;
    float k;

    //Pull in initial data
    printf("Enter as integers without spaces: Number of Segments - Length, Number of Segments - time ,value\n");
    scanf("%d,%d,%f", &width,&maxt,&rvalue);

    float tempvstime[width][maxt];

    fprintf(stderr,"Initializing with %d segments...",width);
    //at t0 -> temp = 100sin(pi*x)
    for(i = 0; i < width; ++i)
      tempvstime[i][0] = 100*sin((M_PI*i)/(width-1));
    fprintf(stderr,"done.\n");

    for(t = 0; t <(maxt-1); ++t){
      for(i = 0; i < width; ++i){
        if( i == 0 || i == (width-1) ){
          tempvstime[i][t+1] = 0;
        } else {
          tempvstime[i][t+1] = rvalue*tempvstime[i-1][t] + (1-2*rvalue)*tempvstime[i][t] + rvalue*tempvstime[i+1][t];
        }
      }
    }

    for(t = 0; t < maxt; t++){
      for(i = 0; i < width; i++)
        printf("%f,",tempvstime[i][t]);
      printf("\n");
    }

}
```